# what is a mutually recursive type?

Tags: types, sml, ml, recursive-datastructures, mutual-recursion

If in ML, an example of a recursive datatype is:

```
datatype llist = Nil | Node of int * llist
```

What is a mutually recursive datatype and whats an example of it, in ML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One such example could be these stupid datatypes.

```
datatype a = A | Ab of b
and      b = B | Ba of a
```

They make no sense, but they show that it is possible to use the `and` keyword (just as with functions) to reference something "ahead" which is normally not possible

They are mutually *(as they both...)* recursive *(...reference each other)*

Answer (score 2):

The standard basic example of mutually recursive data types is a tree and a forest: a forest is a list of trees, while a tree is a value and a forest (the value of the root and the subtrees of its children). In Standard ML this can be defined as follows, allowing empty trees:

```
datatype 'a tree = Empty | Node of 'a * 'a forest
and      'a forest = Nil | Cons of 'a tree * 'a forest
```

from “[Data Types](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/introsml/core/datatypes.htm)”, Programming in Standard ML, by Robert Harper (2000).

Another example is defining expressions in a formal grammar via production rules, such as the following for parenthesized arithmetic expressions of integers:

```
datatype int_exp = plus of int_term * int_term
                 | minus of int_term * int_term
and     int_term = times of int_factor * int_factor
                 | divide of int_factor * int_factor
                 | modulo of int_factor * int_factor
and   int_factor = int_const of int
                 | paren of int_exp;
```

from “[Defining datatypes](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/stg/NOTES/node41.html)”.

I’ve updated “[Mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion)” at Wikipedia to give examples (including Standard ML).