# Example 8.1.2-1 Of Java Language Specification(Mutually Recursive Type Variable Bounds)

Tags: java, recursion, jls

I was reading `jls 8` and I got stuck on [Example 8.1.2-1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2), `Mutually Recursive Type Variable Bounds` I searched stackoverflow, and found a question [what is a mutually recursive type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947203/what-is-a-mutually-recursive-type) but this was not in terms of Java.

*Example 8.1.2-1. Mutually Recursive Type Variable Bounds*

```
interface ConvertibleTo<T> {
    T convert();
}
class ReprChange<T extends ConvertibleTo<S>,
                 S extends ConvertibleTo<T>> { 
    T t; 
    void set(S s) { t = s.convert();    } 
    S get()       { return t.convert(); } 
}
```

#### Question:

- What does *Recursive Type* and *Mutually Recursive Type* means in Java?
- Here what does `T extends ConvertibleTo<S>, S extends ConvertibleTo<T>` means?
- If I just use `T extends ConvertibleTo<S>` as *type parameter* for class ReprChange I am getting compile time error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*What does Recursive Type and Mutually Recursive Type means in Java?*

A recursive type is a type that uses itself in its definition. The simplest example is the linked list:

```
class List<T> {
    T value;
    List<T> next;
}
```

Here, List<T> is recursively defined because it uses a List<T> in its own definition.

A **type variable bound** (*Foo* in <T> extends Foo) is recursive if it references itself, e.g.

```
class Bar<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

would mean that class Bar expects a parameter T that can be compared to a T, so T references itself in its own definition.

Mutual recursion between two things means that they reference each other in their definition. In this case, the definition of S uses T and the definition of T uses S, so their definition is mutually recursive.

*Here what does T extends ConvertibleTo<S>, S extends ConvertibleTo<T> means?*

S and T are two types, S extends interface ConvertibleTo with T as the value of its type parameter, T extends interface ConvertibleTo with S as the value of its parameter. This implies that S has a method T convert() and T has a method S convert(). In other words, you can convert any S to a T and any T to an S.

*If I just use T extends ConvertibleTo<S> as type parameter for class ReprChange I am getting compile time error?*

Yes, because your definition mentions a type parameter named S that is never defined.

Comment: Is this a new feature of Java 8? It looks pretty powerful.

Comment: It has been there for as long as I have known generics in Java, which predates Java 8. It may date back to Java 5, when generics were introduced, but I couldn't confirm this.