# JAVA interface ineritance from custom objects

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

How is the interface extends with the nueron object type still valid when the Nueron class implements the SomeNeurons and has to give the implementation for the Iterable methods. This confuses me on the terms of defining the Iterable type to be of Nueron type even when the implementation is not completed and the compiler is allowing the object type to compile and have a run time for the code.

[image: I have a Nueron and]

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, is it about the mutual recursion of the type `SomeNeurons` which depend on type `Neuron` which in turn depends on `SomeNeuiron`? Is that mutual recursive dependency what confuses you?

Comment: You may want to read about [mutually recursive types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type) or [this similar question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23271203/697630).