# foldr/foldl with logic operators in SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, fold, ml

I'm trying to build a function in SML using `foldr` or `foldl` that will return the logic or and logic and of all elements in a list.

I've tried in this way, using **and** and **or**:

```
fun band x = foldr (op and) true x;
fun bor x = foldr (op or) false x;
```

And also using **andalso** and **orelse**. But I keep receiving error messages such as:

```
Error: unbound variable or constructor: or
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Answer instead of comment.)* Consider using `List.all : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool` and `List.exists : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool` since they're short-circuiting, unlike `List.foldl`. There is really no point in folding farther than the first `false` in `band`'s case, or `true` in `bor`'s case. That is,

```
val band = List.all (fn b => b)
val bor = List.exists (fn b => b)
```

One definition for these library functions is found [here](https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/mosmllib/List.sml#L90):

```
fun all p []      = true
  | all p (x::xr) = p x andalso all p xr;

fun exists p []      = false
  | exists p (x::xr) = p x orelse exists p xr;
```

Since the list being fed to `band` and `bor` are already of type `bool`, passing the identity function `(fn b => b)` will produce the desired truth value. The functions are generic enough to work on any kind of list for which you can apply a predicate for each element, so if you were generating your `bool list` from some other list, you could avoid that step.

Comment: I upvoted all the answers, since they're all good, but this one is clearly the best, precisely because `List.all` and `List.exists` short-circuit where `List.foldl` doesn't.

Comment: This way is more concise and I guess I could say it's also more efficient since it's short-circuiting. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've found out the problem: `andalso` and `orelse` are not operators nor functions cause they implement a [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Therefore, the solution should be:

```
fun band x = foldl (fn (a,b) => a andalso b) true x;
fun bor x = foldr (fn (a,b) => a orelse b) false x;
```

Comment: that doesn't explain why `and` and `or` don't work tho. `and` and `or` don't use short-circuit evaluation so shouldn't your first code work? Disclaimer: I don't know SML but I started reading about it for your question. I'd just like to know the difference ^_^

Comment: @naomik: `and` and `or` are not even operators. `and` is a keyword used for chaining mutually dependent *declarations* together, e.g. value declarations like mutually recursive functions, or type declarations. I.e. `and` doesn't operate on values. See for example the question [what is a mutually recursive type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947203/what-is-a-mutually-recursive-type)

Comment: @JéssicaCarneiro: Consider using `List.all (fn x => x)` and `List.any (fn x => x)` since they are also, unlike `List.foldl`, short-circuiting. There is really no point in folding farther than the first `false` in `band`'s case / `true` in `bor`'s case.

Comment: @SimonShine I'm not sure if I understood. You mean something like: `fun band x = List.all(fn (a,b) => a andalso b) x;` ?

Answer (score 3):

There are no operators called `and` and `or` in SML. `and` is a keyword to separate multiple variable or declarations that are declared at the same time. There is no `or`.

The AND and OR logical operators are `andalso` and `orelse` which as you said in your own answer are short-circuiting, and not regular operators.